# Excel Vlookup or Index Match questions. "duplicate values" with date range factor

Tags: excel, date, indexing, match, vlookup

I have 2 excel files. One lists all activities by a person by date for 2022. The other is a member listing showing start and end dates of a member's status. I want to search by name in the activity file to return a member status in the member listing file. There may be multiple listings for one person if they changed their status through the year, so I need to use the activity date to figure out which member status was valid for that time.

Having a hell of a time trying to put this together. ChatGPT is melting down over it, so I've gone that route already. I don't want to use arrays since it freezes my laptop. This seems very possible.